# Как присоединиться к opensource-разработке?

Tags: работа, opensource

Как известно, существует масса уже написанного либо находящегося в стадии разработки свободного программного обеспечения, либо же ПО с открытым исходным кодом, с открытыми для всех желающих репозиториями SourceForge, GitHub, и других ресурсах.
Собственно говоря, возник вопрос, как можно присоединиться к работе над подобными проектами?
Что для этого нужно, какая квалификация, где можно найти документацию по коду?
Кто будет осуществлять проверку написанного мной кода?
Спасибо.

Comment: У вас у же есть ваш код в каких-нибудь open-source проектах? Патчи/баг-репорты? Вы хотите присоединиться к разработке какого-то определенного проекта, или просто быть open-soruce разработчиком?

Answer (score 17):

Для того, чтобы стать полноценным участником опен-сорсного проекта надо получить статус коммиттера. Путь к получению статуса коммиттера довольно долгий и муторный. Рекомендованный способ это:

1. Сначала стать контрибутором (то есть человеком вносящим какой-то вклад). Обычно это написание какой-нить статейки в wiki проекта. Лучше всего начать с перевода какого-то раздела документации на русский :)
2. Полезно на этом этапе выкачать бинарники проекта, погонять и найти баг. Далее надо сделать баг-репорт. У каждого проекта своя система отслеживания багов: часто это что-то вроде [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) или какие-нибудь новомодные веб системы.
3. Далее подробно изучаем стиль кодирования принятый в проекте. Обычно руководители проектов оч. придирчивы к стилю кодирования. Шаг влево-шаг вправо расстрел на месте
4. Изучаем список багов проекта. Выбираем целевой баг который вы будет фиксить. Лучше всего взять какой-нибудь легонький бажочек не критический и не дай бог new feature - корифеи проекта все равно растерзают по каким-нибудь идейным соображениям
5. Делаем чекаут исходников прожекта (обычно это SVN или Git) - естественно надо изучить целевой VCS - особливо место где рассказывается про транк и ветки репозитория
6. Фиксим баг и выкладываем его либо в виде отдельной ветки в VCS (если это дозволяется правилами проекта) или создаем patch файлик который постится в специальное место проекта.
7. Если все пройдет удачно то с энной попытки ваш коммит будет принят и внедрен в trunk (основной ствол разработки) проекта.
8. Несколько таких успешных багфиксов и можно уже подавать заявку на получение статуса коммиттера.

В общем как-то так.

**P.S.** Инструкция верхнего уровня для контрибуторов проектов Apache [лежит здесь](http://www.apache.org/dev/contributors.html) - удачи.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный и развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд проект должен быть вам интересен, на одном желании "влиться в OpenSource проект" вы далеко не уедете - просто надоест.

Найдите OpenSource продукт которым пользуетесь, найдите в нем какие-либо изъяны или вещи которые вы считаете менее удобными, или фичи которых там нет и допилите их.

Квалификация фактически роли не играет, никто перед merge'м не будет спрашивать над чем вы работали или где учились, главное чтобы код был хорошим, а то что вашего уровня еще не достаточно вы и сами поймете, когда увидите код.

Еще есть вариант начать писать что-то свое, и быть этот проект будет замечен community.

Comment: Интересен, но я как посмотрел код того же ffdshow (я хотел разработать модуль компрессора для выравнивания уровней звука в разных частях фильма), то стало страшно. Там не то чтобы что-то править, мне там даже понять пока что-то очень затруднительно. Надеюсь в будущем ситуация исправится конечно, но пока обидно так вот отказываться от своей идеи только из-за того что сложно понять чужой код.

Answer (score 1):

Возможен такой вариант: Скачиваете код с репозитория и реализуете какую-то фичу или фиксите баги, в зависимости от того, что вы хотите. Отправляете этот патч главному руководителю интересующего вас проекта. После этого он смотрит код и отклоняет или принимает этот патч. В результате он может принять вас в число активных коммитеров. И  по прошествии некоторого времени ваши коммиты будут проверяться меньше времени, смотря какое качество кода вы продемонстрируете в своих патчах.